# Размножается картинка 3ds max

Tags: 3dsmax

Вставляю картинку на plane, она постоянно размножается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. в диффузной карте убери галочку с Real World size.
2. измени количество Tilling на 1.
3. примени к объекту planar модификатор UVW map.
4. в настройках модификатора выбери Planar и убери галочку с Use Real World Size.

И всё должно наложится как надо (если же что-то поплыло проверь Gizmo правильно ли он расположен но до этого дойти не должно)